# How do I change the main page in jekyll hydejack theme in github blog?

Tags: github, jekyll

I made a github blog using jekyll hydejack.
I want to change the main page and know where to load this.

(The main page I'm talking about is the page that moves when you click on the blog name. = It also refers to the page that is accessed when entering the top-level domain.)
I'm using a starter kit.

Comment: Please share the blog link and elaborate on the issue.